# angularjs got XMLHttpRequest cannot load . Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 when do http.delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I got fail when I want to peform $http.delete so there's my code

**script.js**

```
for(var i = 0;i<$scope.ress.length;i++)
    {
        $http.delete("http://localhost:22345/access_menu/" + $scope.ress[i])
        .success(function(res){
            if(res.error == 0)
            {
                console.log("data erased:" + $scope.ress);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("fail erased" + $scope.ress);
            }
        });
    }
```

my rest API

```
app.delete("/access_menu/:_id",function(req,res){
accessmenu.remove({_id:req.params.id},function(err,accmenu){
    if(err)
    {
        data['error'] = 1;
        data['Access_Menu'] = err;
        res.json(data);
    }
    else
    {
        data['error'] = 0;
        res.json(data);
    }
});});
```

model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

var accessmenu = new Schema({
  _id : ObjectId,
  acc_id : String,
  name : String,
  read : Boolean,
  execute : Boolean
},{ collection: 'access_menu'});

var accessmenu = mongoose.model("accessmenu",accessmenu);
module.exports.accessmenu = accessmenu;
```

the error that I found in the console is

so, what the real cause? I already test my rest api in post man and it's working. but when i want to implement it on my angularj, igotthe error message on console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:22345/access_menu/57bd5c19e7cc86f42cb6c825. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

so what should I do to fix it, thank you

**update**

finaly I found the problem, it's happend when I try to crate header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,etc) co I change it with this

```
app.use(function (req,res,next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");     
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","X-Requested-With,X-HTTP-Methods- Override,Content-Type,Accept,Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin,Authorization, Content-Type");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
if ('OPTIONS' == req.method){
    return res.send(200);
}
next();
});
```

so, thanks for all answer and sugestion

Comment: "I already test my rest api in post man" — Which isn't subject to the Same Origin Policy so is useless for dealing with CORS related issues.

Comment: "so what should I do to fix it" — The same thing you do for any 404 error. Make the server response (to the OPTIONS request) with something appropriate.